# Finding if an English word exists in a string of random characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to calculate the probability that an English word exists in a string of variable length; let's say 10 characters. I have the code for the printing of random characters of variable length, but I cannot figure out how to check if an English word exists.

I don't need to check for a specific word — I need to check if *any* English word exists within this string of variable length.

I've two questions — either how do I do this for a string of 10 characters or, which would help a lot as well, how to do this for a string of any length.

The code for the random characters is:

```
def infmonktyp():
  out = " "
  count = 0
  length = int(input("How many characters do you want to print? "))
  for i in range(1, length+1):
    num = randint(1,26)
    out += switcher.get(num, "0")
  print(out)
```

and switcher is a dictionary containing the numbers 1-26 paired with A-Z respectively.

If my input is 10, then the string could be something like "BFGEHDUEND" and the output should be the string "BFGEHDUEND" and True, because the string contains an English word ("END").

Comment: Can u pls show what u have tried. What is your input and what is your desired output?

Comment: "any english word". So, if any of the characters is an "a" or an "i", you have a hit?

Comment: Well you would first need a dictionary and then for all possible slices of the string check if the word is in the dictionary although this aproach may miss conjugated versions of verbs, but it is a good start.

Comment: Please post some code and take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Good call - I didn't think of that. Either way, my code currently is:                        
def infmonktyp():
  out = " "
  count = 0
  length = int(input("How many characters do you want to print? "))
  for i in range(1, length+1):
    num = randint(1,26)
    out += switcher.get(num, "0")
  print(out)              --- where switcher is a dictionary containing the numbers 1-26 assigned to A-Z. If my input is 10, then my string could be "BDGEHFJEND" and I would want the program to print "True", as the string contains the English word "End". No single "A" or single "I".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have a solution for you which will work not only in English but other languages as well (if supported by NLTK).

We're going to use NLTK to get a set of all English words (which is documented [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html), section 4.1.), which we assign to `english`

We're then looping through the variable `out` and slicing it at all possible places, with a minimum length of 2 letters, and appending the results to a new list called `all_variants`.

Finally we loop through the 'words' in `all_variants`, check if they are in our variable `english` and print the response appropriately.

```
# imports 
import nltk
import string
import random

# getting the alphabet
alph = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase]
# creating your dictionary
switcher = {}
for i in range(1, 27):
    switcher[i] = alph[i-1]
# using nltk we are going to get a set of all english words
english = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())


def infmonktyp(english_dict = english, letter_dictionary = switcher): 
    out = "" 
    count = 0 
    length = int(input("How many characters do you want to print?"))
    if length < 2:
        raise ValueError("Length must be greater than 1")
    for i in range(1, length+1): 
        num = random.randint(1,26) 
        out += letter_dictionary.get(num, "0") 
    # the random word has been created
    print(out)
    all_variants = []
    # getting all variants of the word, minimum of 2 letters
    for i in range(len(out)-1):
        for j in range(i+2, len(out)+1):
            all_variants.append(out[i:j])
    # for know how many words we found, im gussing thats what you have in the second line?
    words_found = 0
    # looping through all the words, if they exist in english, print them, if not keep going
    for word in all_variants:
        if word in english_dict:
            print(word, ' found in ', out)
            words_found += 1
    # if we didnt find any words, print that we didnt find any words
    if words_found == 0:
        print("Couldn't find a word")

# initialising function
infmonktyp(english, switcher)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed! I apologize if my question was confusing. It works perfectly! I'll mark the question as answered.